# PySpark pattern matching and assigning associated values

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**df1**:

```
campaign_name   campaign_team
einsurancep09   other
estoreemicardcdwpnov06  other
estoreemicardwmnov06    other
estoreemicardgenericspnov06 other
```

**df2**:

```
terms   product_category    product
insurance   insurance   null
def emi store
ab  bhi asd
de  lic cards
a   credit  cards
```

Below are my scenarios:

1. '`terms`' column (df2) is sorted according to the string length in descending order.
2. It should be compared with the `campaign_name` of df1 for `contains/like`.
3. Whichever `terms` string `matches first` with the `campaign_name`, its product_category and product should be picked up and should be added as new columns in df1.
4. For `campaign_name` value "`einsurancep09`", "`insurance`" value from `terms` is contained in campaign_name so its product_category and product is picked up and added as df1 in the output.
5. Another eg: Consider rest 3 records where you `contain` `def`, `ab` and `de` in the `campaign_name` string but we are picking product_category and product of "`def`" as it `appeared first` and is the `longest in the length` when compared with "ab" and "de"

Below is my code:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("product_category",when(df1.campaign_name.contains(df2.terms),df2.product_category).otherwise('other'))
```

But, it gives me below error:

```
   raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) terms#37,product_category#38 missing from campaign_name#16,campaign_team#17 in operator !Project [campaign_name#16, campaign_team#17, CASE WHEN Contains(campaign_name#16, terms#37) THEN product_category#38 ELSE other END AS product_category#44].;
!Project [campaign_name#16, campaign_team#17, CASE WHEN Contains(campaign_name#16, terms#37) THEN product_category#38 ELSE other END AS product_category#44]
+- Relation[campaign_name#16,campaign_team#17] csv
```

So where am I going wrong?

As per stack's answer, I am getting below output:

```
+---------------+-------------+---------+----------------+-------+
|campaign_name  |campaign_team|terms    |product_category|product|
+---------------+-------------+---------+----------------+-------+
|einsurancepnm06|other        |insurance|Insurance       |NaN    |
+---------------+-------------+---------+----------------+-------+
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: can you share samples in text format

Comment: Like how do you want me to share ?

Comment: "de" also matches with all the records in campaign_name.. why it is not included in the output.

Comment: when you are pasting in the question.. make it "paste as plain text"..

Comment: Okay. The thing is whichever string satisfies "contains" requirement, its associated values should be picked up that's why "de" and "abc" are not considered here.

Comment: "de" also satisfies all the requirements of "def".. so how is it not in the output

Comment: As I said earlier whichever string matches first from df2 ( df1). I hope it is clear now

Comment: then you need the specify the row number or the order of df1 records..

Comment: Please update question with proper format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the volume of dataframe `df2` is high, *then the spark will not be optimized to perform such operations*. If it is not (< 200 records) then there are two feasible approaches that we can use for solving this:

- **CROSS Join**
- **UDF**

**Approach 1: CROSS Join**

**Steps:**

1. Add new column `rw` and assign row number as per require order in `df2`.
2. Cross Join `df1` and sorted `df2` and create a new dataframe `df3`.
3. Use contains columnar function and add new column `match`.
4. Select the first Row after partition By all `df1` columns and order by `df2` row number and `match` column

**Code**

```
>>> df1.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------+-------------+
|campaign_name              |campaign_team|
+---------------------------+-------------+
|einsurancep09              |other        |
|estoreemicardcdwpnov06     |other        |
|estoreemicardwmnov06       |other        |
|estoreemicardgenericspnov06|other        |
|abcdefcdwpnov06            |other        |
|abcdefwmnov06              |other        |
|abcdefgenericspnov06       |other        |
+---------------------------+-------------+

>>> df2.show(truncate=False)
+---------+----------------+-------+---+
|terms    |product_category|product|rw |
+---------+----------------+-------+---+
|insurance|insurance       |null   |1  |
|def      |emi             |store  |2  |
|ab       |bhi             |asd    |3  |
|de       |lic             |cards  |4  |
|a        |credit          |cards  |5  |
+---------+----------------+-------+---+

>>> df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
>>> df4 = df3.withColumn("match", col("campaign_name").contains(col("terms")))
>>> W = Window.partitionBy(col("campaign_name"), col("campaign_team")).orderBy(col("match").desc(), col("rw"))

>>> finalDF = df4.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(W)).filter(col("rn") == lit(1)).drop("rn", "terms","rw","match")
>>> finalDF.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
|campaign_name              |campaign_team|product_category|product|
+---------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
|estoreemicardgenericspnov06|other        |credit          |cards  |
|abcdefwmnov06              |other        |emi             |store  |
|estoreemicardcdwpnov06     |other        |credit          |cards  |
|estoreemicardwmnov06       |other        |credit          |cards  |
|einsurancep09              |other        |insurance       |null   |
|abcdefgenericspnov06       |other        |emi             |store  |
|abcdefcdwpnov06            |other        |emi             |store  |
+---------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
```

**Approach 2 UDF**

**Steps**:

1. Add new column `rw` and assign row number as per require order in `df2`.
2. based on row number collect all `df2` rows into a single row and create a new Dataframe `df3`.
3. Use any approach from below and create a new Dataframe df4.

   - Convert the `df3` row into String Variable and add String literal as a new column in `df1`.
     Or
   - cross Join `df1` and `df3`.
4. Declare `UDF` as below.
5. Call `UDF` and add a new column with the return value.
6. Create require columns from output returns.

**Code**

```
>>> df3 = df2.na.fill("").groupBy(lit(1)).agg(sort_array(collect_list(concat(col("rw"),lit(":"), col("terms"), lit(":"), col("product_category"), lit(":"), col("product")))).alias("Check")).withColumn("Check", concat_ws(",", col("Check"))).drop("1")
>>> df3.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Check                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1:insurance:insurance:,2:def:emi:store,3:ab:bhi:asd,4:de:lic:cards,5:a:credit:cards|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

>>> df4 = df1.crossJoin(df3)
>>> def categoryFunction(name, Check):
        checkList = Check.lower().split(",")
        out = ""
        match = False
        for Key in checkList:
            keyword = Key.split(":",2)
            terms = keyword[1]
            tempOut = keyword[2]
            if terms in name.lower():
                out = tempOut
                match = True
            if match:
                break
        return out
   
>>> categoryUDF = udf(categoryFunction, StringType())
>>> finalDF = df4.withColumn("out", categoryUDF(col("campaign_name"), col("Check"))).drop("Check").withColumn("out", split(col("out"), ":")).withColumn("product_category", col("out")[0]).withColumn("product", col("out")[1]).drop("out").show(truncate=False)
>>> finalDF.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
|campaign_name              |campaign_team|product_category|product|
+---------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
|einsurancep09              |other        |insurance       |       |
|estoreemicardcdwpnov06     |other        |credit          |cards  |
|estoreemicardwmnov06       |other        |credit          |cards  |
|estoreemicardgenericspnov06|other        |credit          |cards  |
|abcdefcdwpnov06            |other        |emi             |store  |
|abcdefwmnov06              |other        |emi             |store  |
|abcdefgenericspnov06       |other        |emi             |store  |
+---------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------+
```

Comment: I can see the efforts behind this answer. Thank you so much @Nikk for this detailed answer. It worked like a charm. Just ran it and it worked but will have to understand the code. I Will let you know if I didn't get any of the lines. Definitely new learning!

Answer (score 1):

Assumption

Dataset df1 should have an order to meet the OP requirement. So I introduce the rec_no column

```
df = spark.sql("""
select 'abcdefcdwpnovo6' campaign_name, 'other' campaign_team union all
select 'abcdefdwpnovo6' , 'other' union all
select 'abcdefgenericpnovo6' , 'other' 
""")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df.show()

+-------------------+-------------+
|      campaign_name|campaign_team|
+-------------------+-------------+
|    abcdefcdwpnovo6|        other|
|     abcdefdwpnovo6|        other|
|abcdefgenericpnovo6|        other|
+-------------------+-------------+

df1 = spark.sql("""
select 1 rec_no, 'def' terms, 'emi' product_category, 'store' product union all 
select 2, 'abc' ,'bhi' ,'asd' union all
select 3, 'de' ,'lic' ,'cards' union all
select 4, 'a' ,'credit' ,'cards' 
""")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df1.show()

+------+-----+----------------+-------+
|rec_no|terms|product_category|product|
+------+-----+----------------+-------+
|     1|  def|             emi|  store|
|     2|  abc|             bhi|    asd|
|     3|   de|             lic|  cards|
|     4|    a|          credit|  cards|
+------+-----+----------------+-------+
```

Output:

You can drop the ps, rk and rec_no columns

```
spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select * from df a cross join df1 b ),
     t2 ( select rec_no, campaign_name,campaign_team,terms,product_category,product x, position(terms,campaign_name) ps,
    rank() over(order by rec_no) rk from t1  where position(terms,campaign_name)>0 )
    select * from t2 where rk=1
""").show()

+------+-------------------+-------------+-----+----------------+-----+---+---+
|rec_no|      campaign_name|campaign_team|terms|product_category|    x| ps| rk|
+------+-------------------+-------------+-----+----------------+-----+---+---+
|     1|    abcdefcdwpnovo6|        other|  def|             emi|store|  4|  1|
|     1|     abcdefdwpnovo6|        other|  def|             emi|store|  4|  1|
|     1|abcdefgenericpnovo6|        other|  def|             emi|store|  4|  1|
+------+-------------------+-------------+-----+----------------+-----+---+---+
```

Update-1:

The OP's question is still not clear. Try below.

```
spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select * from df a cross join df1 b ),
     t2 ( select rec_no, campaign_name,campaign_team,terms,product_category,product, position(product_category,campaign_name) ps,
    rank() over(partition by product_category order by rec_no) rk from t1 where position(product_category,campaign_name)>0 
    )
    select * from t2 where rk=1 order by rec_no
""").show(truncate=False)

+------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------+-------+---+---+
|rec_no|campaign_name              |campaign_team|terms    |product_category|product|ps |rk |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------+-------+---+---+
|1     |einsurancep09              |other        |insurance|insurance       |null   |2  |1  |
|2     |estoreemicardcdwpnov06     |other        |def      |emi             |store  |7  |1  |
|2     |estoreemicardgenericspnov06|other        |def      |emi             |store  |7  |1  |
|2     |estoreemicardwmnov06       |other        |def      |emi             |store  |7  |1  |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------+-------+---+---+
```

Comment: Let me try this in sometime and will let u know

Comment: Thank you for your answer @stack. Could you please explain the query? Also, my bad, I didn't cover the other scenario. Suppose if I change my dataset then I get only 1 record. I have updated my question

Comment: I have updated the question with the datasets and outputs. New to this but trying my best to learn

Comment: and if I remove rk=1, I get duplicates

Comment: It gives me blank records as per your second updated answer. Also, I have edited my question for better clarity

Comment: Thanks for your efforts as well, Stack. Much appreciated!